# Submitting Spark Application through command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I have a Spark Application which I initially created using maven. I converted my maven project into an Eclipse project, and I am now working on it via Eclipse.

I also have my own version of the Spark source code to which I have made some modifications and added additional methods. I am able to build my version of Spark and obtain the jar file for spark-core.

In my Eclipse project I now replace the spark-core that is in the build path with the newly built spark-core jar. I am able to utilize the new methods I created and verify this by running the application through Eclipse.

Now, I am trying to submit my application through the command line. I use the spark-submit command from the Spark project I have modified. When I submit my jar, I get an error saying the method I created does not exist. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate some insight on what I should be doing.

**UPDATE**

I now understand that there are certain jars that I need to have from my custom build. Exactly which jars are these? I understand the spark-assembly jar is one. Are there any others?

Comment: What is your spark-submit command?

Comment: spark/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master spark://xxx:7077 --total-executor-cores 32 /home/ec2-user/spark1.jar

Comment: Are you sure your modified spark code got compiled into the spark assembly jar? It's a jar under {spark_home}/lib/ with the name like spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop1.0.4.jar. It is like the uber jar for all major spark runtime jars, including spark-core.

Comment: ah, thanks for that information. But, it looks like it didn't get built. I don't even see a lib folder in the spark home dir. But, when I execute spark-submit I can still submit applications. If I remove the new method I added and recreate my application jar, it runs. Is there somewhere else where the assembly jar would be located?